# Error Package Manage

Tags: package-management

```
[An unresolvable problem occurred while initializing the package information.

Please report this bug against the 'update-manager' package and include the following error message:
E:Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

How can I fix it?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
sudo apt update --fix-missing
sudo dpkg -configure -a 
sudo apt install -f
```

Essentially, you are updating the packages while fixing any broken ones.  Then the next two are different ways to resolve broken package and dependencies. 
Once those commands are finished, try running an update.

Comment: Once those commands are finished, try running an update. If there is still an issue, please give more details.